# import ants causes AttributeError for scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy

I am running Spyder 3.3.6 on CentOS.  I installed with

```
/home/peter/anaconda3/bin/pip install https://github.com/ANTsX/ANTsPy/releases/download/v0.2.0/antspyx-0.2.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

When I enter

```
import scipy
from scipy import stats
```

I get no errors.  However, when I enter

```
import ants
```

I get

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'stats'
```

Comment: Is this the `ants` that you are using: https://pypi.org/project/antspyx/ ?

Comment: I followed that link and installed antspyx as recommended by that link.  I have updated my question accordingly.   Unfortunately, the same problem persists.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import scipy.stats
```

Instead of

```
from scipy import stats
```

Comment: I tried "import scipy.stats" followed by "import ants".  I still get the error "AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'stats'". The problem appears to be in the antspyx package. Thanks,

Comment: Antspyx would definitely be your problem, yeah. I'm able to run it with no issues, hope you can fix it.